# How to avoid matching too much?

Tags: regex, sqlite, replace

I have an HTML string:

```
<li>bmasdas asmdasmdamsd admasmams asmdamsdma asmdamsdasm </li> 
<li> asdmams sdasdasmdamsdma asdmsasdaddamsdasm </li> 
<li> dsadasdasdas TARGET dasdasdsa</li>
```

I'm trying to capture `<li>` tags that contain the word "TARGET" with this regex:

```
<li.*?TARGET.*?\/li>
```

While this does capture the line I wanted, the match starts at the first `<li>`. How can I only capture the tags I want?

Comment: sorry for my bad understanding..but can you be a bit more elaborate

Comment: **pease copy this:** <li>bmasdas asmdasmdamsd admasmams asmdamsdma asmdamsdasm </li><li> asdmams sdasdasmdamsdma asdmsasdaddamsdasm </li> <li> dsadasdasdas TARGET dasdasdsa</li>  **and use my regexp, you will see regexp matches whole text, but i want to match only last string (line)**

Comment: please rephrase your question: "t works fine when you consider regexp stops with the last '<\li>, doesn't go ahead, however i am trying to find a way it would not go and read all other lines with <'li> before TARGET."

Comment: if you copy the code I pasted to Rock321987,  and use the regexp i shared with you, you will notice regexp would match whole string. But I want it to match only string where word TARGET exists. Only this line, only the string with **<li>...Target...</li>** I want to get only this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't seem to understand that `.` matches any character, including the ones in `<li`. By changing this, it is possible to parse simple HTML.

Try this: `<li[^<]*TARGET[^>]*\/li>`

The difference is that I used negated char classes, like `[^>]` to ensure it doesn't catch the tags. Note that regex isn't the tool to use if there are nested tags.